# Read file content into Arraylist using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, file, deserialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am a beginner in java and practicing IO stream and Serialization .In below problem unable to read all data into a Arraylist and print it. by using the ObjectOutputStream insert the content by user in file but unable to get all data. just first part of data are read.

```java
package com.filehandling;
import java.io.*;

public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name ;
    private int age;
    private String role;
    private int number;
    User(){}
    public User(String name1, int age1, String role1, int number1){
         this.name = name1;
         this.age = age1;
         this.role = role1;
         this.number = number1;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
 
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }
 
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
 
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
 
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

 
 
   @Override
    public String toString() {
    
        return new StringBuffer(" Name : ").append(this.name)
                .append(", role : ").append(this.role).append(", Age : ").append(this.age).append(" Number : ").append(this.number).toString();
    }
 
}
```

```java
package com.filehandling;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Menu {
    String name, role;
    int age,number;
    //User user1 = new User();
    File f = new File("students.txt");
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Menu main = new Menu();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 for Add data");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for Printing all data");
        System.out.println("Enter 3 to Exit");
        scan.hasNextLine();
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        scan.hasNextLine();
        
        //String extra = scan.nextLine();
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                main.callWriteFile();
                
                break;
            case 2:
                main.callReadFile();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nInvalid Choice !");
                break;
        }
    }
}

    public void callWriteFile() {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
            Menu main = new Menu();
            System.out.println("enter name, role, age, number");
            
            
             name = scan.nextLine();
             role = scan.nextLine();
             age = scan.nextInt();
             number = scan.nextInt();
             
            User user = new User(name,age,role,number);
            main.writeData(user);
            
            
    }
    catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public void callReadFile() throws IOException {
        Menu main = new Menu();
        ArrayList<Object> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
        main.readFile(objectsList);
        
    for(Object user1: objectsList) {
            System.out.println(user1);  
        }

        
        System.out.println(objectsList);
        }
        



     public ArrayList<Object> readFile(ArrayList<Object> list) throws IOException{
         
         FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("students.txt");
        ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(file);
//       ArrayList<Object> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
         boolean counter = true;
         while (counter) {
           try  {
             Object object = input.readObject();
             if (object != null) {
             User userTest = (User) object;
                if( userTest !=null){
                    System.out.println(" my  "+userTest);
                }
               list.add(object);
             }
             input.close();
             
               counter = false;
             }
            
           catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
           }
            }
        // input.close();
         return list;
         
     }
    
    public void writeData(Object obj) {
        try{
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("students.txt", true);
            if (f.length() == 0) {
            ObjectOutputStream object = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
    
    
            object.writeObject(obj);
            object.close();
            
            }
            else {
                 MyObjectOutputStream oos = null;
                 oos = new MyObjectOutputStream(file);
                 oos.writeObject(obj);

                 // Closing the FileOutputStream object
                 // to release memory resources
                 oos.close();
            }
            }
        catch(Exception e) {    
            System.out.println(e);

            }
    }
}
```

```java
package com.filehandling;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
 
    // Constructor of this class
    // 1. Default
    MyObjectOutputStream() throws IOException
    {
 
        // Super keyword refers to parent class instance
        super();
    }
 
    // Constructor of this class
    // 1. Parameterized constructor
    MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream o) throws IOException
    {
        super(o);
    }
 
    // Method of this class
    public void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

i tried every possible thing at my level but cannot spot the loophole.

Comment: You should not be using an `ObjectOutputStream` for writing plain text. Consider using `java.nio.file.Files.writeString` or similar methods in that class, which will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: thank you for that, but i want to try serialization that why i use that class

Comment: So is the problem with parsing user input, or writing the file, or reading it back from the file? Serialization is the process of tranforming the object into a representation to transmit or store. That could be plain text, as indicated by your choice of "students.txt" as the filename. Intuitively I would say your `writeData` method is doing something very funky depending on the size of the file. Have you verified that the file contents are as expected after writing, before trying to read them again? Obviously that would be easier when writing a plain String instead of an Object.

Comment: at my understanding problem is reading the data from file. can you brief that what is funky about writeData method

Comment: In `readFile` you are calling `input.close();` within your while loop, while it is commented out after the loop. That closes the input and stops reading once the first object has been read.